# iptables packet header capture and compare

Tags: networking, iptables

We are using multicast program to listen up multicast data from our provider, there are couple cases where the multicast having issue:
1. their server hang, hence no multicast data received from our end
2. their server having issue, multicast connection exists but no data inside
3. Sometime provider send duplicated message to us
4. multicast provider keep sending data to our end, but our listener hang

My question:
Can I use iptables to track a stateful multicast connection and doing some compare like math reduction based on data inside each packet?